# how to use condition in `when` clause in merge statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have tow tables and want to Insert or Updated chages from tableA to TableB.

`PatientId` and `ComposeId` are Compound keys in both tables

```
table A
PatientId
ComposeId 
Name
Family

table B
PatientId
ComposeId 
Name
Family
```

I want to Implement something like this or using nested merge if possible. How to do it?

```
Merge TbleB as Target
using (select PatientId,Compseid,Name,Family from TableA) as source
on (source.PatientId=target.PatientId and source.ComposeId=target.Composeid and source.Name=Target.Name
and Source.Family=target.Family)
when not matched and source.patientId=target.PatientId  and Source.CompositionId=Target.CompistionId
  then update 
      set Name=Source.Name,
      set Family=Source.Family
when not matched and (source.patientId<>target.PatientId  and Source.CompositionId<>Target.CompistionId) then 
   Insert
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've placed too many conditions in your `ON` clause. I think you just want:

```
Merge TbleB as Target
using (select PatientId,Compseid,Name,Family from TableA) as source
on source.PatientId=target.PatientId and source.ComposeId=target.Composeid
when matched --You could add the Name<>Name or Family<>Family WHEN condition here
             --if wanted, but I wouldn't bother usually
  then update 
      set Name=Source.Name,
      set Family=Source.Family
when not matched then 
   Insert
```

Just to point out, the following doesn't make any sense:

```
when not matched and source.patientId=target.PatientId  and Source.CompositionId=Target.CompistionId
```

`when not matched` is saying that there is *no* row in `target` that matches the requirements specified in your `ON` clause. As such, any references to `target` in additional conditions here can't possibly work.